# Live migration on Openstack

Tags: openstack

I'm working on a projet on OpenStack. I have installed OpenStack by creating two virtual machines, one for the controller node and the other for the compute node.
Actually, I want to test an example of live migration on openstack and I have found a video which describes the aproch. As the video shows, I need to have 2 compute nodes, and I want to know if I just need to create a second compute node or this second compute should be created at the phase of installation of openstack.
This is the link of the video that I have watched: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4vJUYFGbEM

Thank you

Comment: This question is really too broad for us to provide you with a useful answer.  There are a variety of guides out there about installing and scaling OpenStack, and there are reasonably explicit instructions about live migration as well.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter when you add the compute nodes (During the install or later on). Please also remember that the live-migration piggy backs on the hypervisor. So depending on hypervisor that one uses, this may or may not be possible.

Please look at this http://docs.openstack.org/admin-guide/compute-configuring-migrations.html#section-configuring-compute-migrations to ensure that the migration capability exists

It simply boils down to a few things

- The storage is not moved in case of a live migration, so if you have a VM with instance storage, you will need to have a shared file system like NFS or something, If you have an instance backed by a cinder volume you will be able do the migration without the shared storage.

  - The Nova-Compute application needs to be installed on the destiantion
  - The hypervisor version should be the same.

I hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 1):

Either works. OpenStack allows you dynamically add and remove computes nodes from a cloud environment.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to http://docs.openstack.org/admin-guide/compute-configuring-migrations.html for extra details.

---

Live migration for light instances can be done over network ,without shared storage, but for heavy instances ,shared storage or shared volume will be preferred. As you mentioned you have two compute nodes ,theirs nova storage should be shared storage.

Answer (score 0):

Long answer short in my perspective,

You can add/remove compute node at any time from an OpenStack installation.
For adding compute, follow installation guide to add new compute node right from environment setup.

Also, dont forget to install networking part in your new Compute node.